# Searching Active Directory users with a contains and OR query

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I've written this code to find users with a display name containing a certain string. I would like to improve this query so that it returns anyone that contains the string in either their `firstname` or `lastname` or `displayname` (right now its only filtering on displayname).

Is that possible? I cant seem to find any examples using OR in these queries/filters.

```
List<ADUser> adUsers = new List<ADUser>();

DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().GetDirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("firstname");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastname");

directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User) (displayname=*" + searchQuery + "*))";

SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult u in searchResultCollection)
{
    var user = new ADUser()
    {
        UserName = u?.Properties?.Contains("samaccountname") == true ? u?.Properties["samaccountname"][0]?.ToString() : String.Empty,
        DisplayName = u?.Properties?.Contains("displayname") == true ? u?.Properties["displayname"][0]?.ToString() : String.Empty,
        FirstName = u?.Properties?.Contains("firstname") == true ? u?.Properties["firstname"][0]?.ToString() : String.Empty,
        LastName = u?.Properties?.Contains("lastname") == true ? u?.Properties["lastname"][0]?.ToString() : String.Empty,
        Email = u?.Properties?.Contains("mail") == true ? u?.Properties["mail"][0]?.ToString() : String.Empty,
        UserGroup = u?.Properties?.Contains("usergroup") == true ? u?.Properties["usergroup"][0]?.ToString() : String.Empty,
    };
    adUsers.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you a search with a wildcard at the beginning can cause poor performance in the query. This is true of any database, because it's impossible to use indexes to find a match. So it needs to go through every single record to find a match. So the performance of this query will drop with the more users your domain has.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `|` which is the OR operator in LDAP:

```
directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(|(displayName=*" + searchQuery + "*)(givenName=*" + searchQuery + "*)(sn=*" + searchQuery + "*)))";
```

Another option would be to use [Ambigious Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) (although this will also apply each word in the search criteria to mail address attributes and the username, not just display name, given name and surname):

```
directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(anr=" + searchQuery + "))";
```

Comment: Thank you. The first example worked great and gave me several results matching from different fields. The second option sounds like it might be more performant but given the same string it yielded no results.

Comment: Also, thank you for fixing my errors in the variable names. Was searching for what they might be and you just answer for me with givenName and sn ;)

Comment: Changing it to "(&(objectClass=User)(anr=" + searchQuery + "))" returns several matches, but when giving it "And" it only finds people with a lastname of "Andersson" and not people with a first name of "Andy".